# New Java developer - Simple Q

Tags: java, loops, input

I have just recently started coding and am quite the beginner. I'm trying to make a program that simply asks the user to enter a "password", and depending on whether the password is correct; increment a counter. And, once the counter reaches 10, print out a message. 
Basically what I'm trying to make is like a "clip-card", like one of those you can get at a coffee shop (you get every 10th coffee free).

So, this is what I have now. I just need to know how to make the program continue after inputting a password, and keep track of the inputs.

Ohhh and... If this is unclear, please say so and I will try to clarify.

This is what I have to far...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Coffee {

public static void main(String [] args){


    int count = 0;
    String pass = "hey";

    System.out.println("Enter password: ");

    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

    String moves = key.nextLine();

    if(moves.compareTo(pass) == 0){

        count++;
        System.out.println("You're one step closer to a free coffe! You have so far bought " + count + " coffe(s)");
    }
    if(count % 10 == 0 && count != 0){
        System.out.println("You've got a free coffe!");
    }
    if(moves.compareTo(pass) != 0){
    System.out.println("Wrong password! Try again.\n");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You'll probably want to use a loop. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: Are you familiar with loops? More specific the while loop?

Comment: Please relate your title to the programming problem your having. For example: "how to make the program continue after inputting a password while keeping track of the inputs" (a shorter title would be more appealing, but at least have it specify the actual problem you are having or question or want answered)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When would your program end? The way you describe it, it could just go on forever.

If that is the case, you just enclose it in a `while` loop :

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner key;
    String moves;
    int count = 0;
    String pass = "hey";
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Enter password: ");
        key = new Scanner(System.in);
        moves = key.nextLine();
        if(moves.compareTo(pass) == 0){
            count++;
            System.out.println("You're one step closer to a free coffe! You have so far bought " + count + " coffe(s)");
        }
        if(count % 10 == 0 && count != 0){
            System.out.println("You've got a free coffe!");
        }
        if(moves.compareTo(pass) != 0){
            System.out.println("Wrong password! Try again.\n");
        }
    }
}
```

But you really should have an breaking condition.

Comment: Well I want my program to work just like a clip card, for every n:th coffee you buy, you get a free one. So, I'd actually need it to be restored to its last position every time it has been run (meaning, if a person has 7 coffees purchases, the program needs to know to start at 7 next time it is being run). 

And about the breaking condition, yes I would need one. Just one that breaks the program and lets it know where to start next time it is being run. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need loop(while,do-while,or for loop) to do this kind of repeated stuff .

Sample code may help

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Coffee {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int count = 0;
    String pass = "hey";

    System.out.println("Enter password: ");

    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);

    String moves = key.nextLine();
    boolean flag = true;
    while (flag) {

        if (moves.compareTo(pass) == 0) {

            count++;
            System.out
                    .println("You're one step closer to a free coffe! You have so far bought "
                            + count + " coffe(s)");
        }
        if (count == 10 && count != 0) {
            System.out.println("You've got a free coffe!");
            count=0;
        }
        if (moves.compareTo(pass) != 0) {
            System.out.println("Wrong password! Try again.\n");
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue ..(y/n)");
        String choice = key.nextLine();
        if (choice.equals("n")) {
            flag = false;
        } else {
            flag = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a while and  do-while loop to chose from

While loop

```
Scanner key;
String moves;
int count = 0;
String pass = "hey";
boolean condition=true;
while(condition) {
    System.out.println("Enter password: ");
    key = new Scanner(System.in);
    moves = key.nextLine();
    if(moves.compareTo(pass) == 0){
        count++;
        System.out.println("You're one step closer to a free coffe! You have so far bought " + count + " coffe(s)");

        if(count % 10 == 0 && count != 0){
        System.out.println("You've got a free coffe!");
        condition=false;
        }
    }
    else if(moves.compareTo(pass) != 0){
        System.out.println("Wrong password! Try again.\n");
    }
}
```

Do-While loop

```
Scanner key;
String moves;
int count = 0;
String pass = "hey";
boolean condition=true;
do{
    System.out.println("Enter password: ");
    key = new Scanner(System.in);
    moves = key.nextLine();
    if(moves.compareTo(pass) == 0){
        count++;
        System.out.println("You're one step closer to a free coffe! You have so far bought " + count + " coffe(s)");

        if(count % 10 == 0 && count != 0){
        System.out.println("You've got a free coffe!");
        condition=false;
        }
    }
    else if(moves.compareTo(pass) != 0){
        System.out.println("Wrong password! Try again.\n");
    }
}while(condition);
```